# Is it possible to automatically open vertical splits in vim?

Tags: vim, split

I would like vim to detect when I am opening several files on the commandline, and automatically open them in (vertical) splits. I know that I can use the `-O` switch. But I sometimes forgot to add it, and would like vim to catch that mistake.

Is there a setting to put in `.vimrc` that would produce such a behavior? Ideally it could be disabled by a specific switch, when I rarely need it.

Something like `set several_files_in_vsplit=1`…

Note: I usually don't open more than 3 files, so the "small sizes of splits" is not really a problem, and I already have a command auto-adjusting the size of the active split.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this behavior in your `.vimrc` by adding the following autocmd:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() > 1 && !exists("s:std_in") | execute "vsp " . argv() | wincmd p | argdelete" | endif
```

This will check if you have opened more than one file and if you haven't already piped any input to Vim, it will automatically open each file in a vertical split. The `| wincmd p | argdelete` will switch back to the first split and delete the argument list, respectively.

You can also disable this behavior by passing the `-n` flag when launching Vim, which prevents reading from stdin, or by passing only one file name as an argument to Vim.

Note that you can adjust the size of the splits using `:vertical resize <size>` after the vertical splits have been created, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible from within vim. But you can get pretty close through an alias, like

```bash
alias vim="vim -O"
```

Then calling `vim file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` will open these files in vertical splits, and simply calling `vim file1.txt` continues to work as before.

This behavior can then be toggled by either defining or undefining this alias. Or alternately you could set up a more complicated bash function that checks for some environment variable, such as `several_files_in_vsplit`, and then either calls vim normally or calls vim with `-O` as an argument.